# constructor dependency for IHostingEnvironment in Asp.Net Core RC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

How Can I create constructor dependency for IHostingEnvironment in my ServiceUtility class. How to bind in the Startup ConfigureServices method the dependency for IHostEnvironment.

**Custom Class**

```
public class ServiceUtility
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _environment;
        public ServiceUtility(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            _environment = environment;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is ninject not feasible for this one?

Comment: DI is built in to ASP.NET Core, so I'd lean toward using that first before introducing another container.

Comment: @maxspan `IHostingEnvironment` service is registered by default. Just register your service `services.AddScoped<ServiceUtility>();`